# How to create a Wind Rose plot in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am attempting to create a wind rose graph, i.e.

[image: here]

[image: here]

My data is wind speed and cardinal wind direction in separate columns:

```
Wind (mph)  Wind Direction
3.66        SE
2.69        SE
2.62        SW
2.76        SW
2.11        NW
3.13        NW
3.55        SW
3.62        W
```

My final goal is to actually create the graph with a VBA macro, but I am unsure how to even create the graph manually.  I can, if need be, convert the cardinal directions to degrees.

Comment: I assume this is next to impossible without external software to create the graph.  I ended up creating the graph in PHP.

Comment: I got curious and googled a little bit: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excelchart/thread/b55089f2-09bc-4599-ad38-785a4709d4e8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create something basic much like your first sample using a standard Excel "filled radar chart". You'll need to summarise your data into a table like this - make sure the higher-valued column comes first. It can probably be done just with some "countif" formulas from your input data, not even VBA.

```
    H   M   L
N   5   4   1
NE  7   5   2
E   9   6   3
SE  11  5   4
S   10  6   5
SW  5   5   4
W   4   3   3
NW  2   1   2
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I researched and believe that the only way to create a wind rose graph in excel 2007 is by using external programs that then import the image into excel.

Since I was seeking a way to create the wind rose completely within excel using a VBA macro, I believe this problem to be currently unsolvable.

Answer (score 2):

I had a good search around and found this site very helpful:

http://www.windroseexcel.com

It's cheap and it simple to use. Runs using excel with some built in VBA coding to produce wind roses like the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.windrose.gr/) has software you can download to do this in Excel. I didn't try it, but from the user manual it looks like what you want. Bonus: available in in English and Greek! ;-)

This [site](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=338231) suggests using R to create the graph. R is statistical computation and graphics package. I've seen some nice output from it. I suspect it will require some work before you will be able to use it efficiently.

Answer (score -2):

It's actually simple - just create a filled radar chart.  Create a column of data with multiple points for each direct, say 10 separated by a null or low value point.

Comment: Could you possibly go into further detail, possibly with test values or a screenshot?